# Static library with multiple .h and .cu files can't resolve functions

Tags: c++, cuda, static-libraries, header-files, unresolved-external

When compiling a static library with multiple.h and .cu files I get an unresolved extern function.  Here is a short example that replicates the error.

It appears that I can't get Nsight Eclipse Edition to compile extrafunctions.cu first.  In my full project the file with extra functions *is* compiled first but it still throws the unable to resolve external function error.

Here's the output for this sample:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project linkerror ****

make all 
Building file: ../cudatest.cu
Invoking: NVCC Compiler
nvcc -I/usr/local/cuda/include -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -odir "" -M -o "cudatest.d" "../cudatest.cu"
nvcc --compile -G -I/usr/local/cuda/include -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_30,code=compute_30 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30  -x cu -o  "cudatest.o" "../cudatest.cu"
../cudatest.cu(19): warning: variable "devInts" is used before its value is set

../cudatest.cu(19): warning: variable "devInts" is used before its value is set

ptxas fatal   : Unresolved extern function '_Z9incrementi'
make: *** [cudatest.o] Error 255

**** Build Finished ****
```

cudatest.h:

```
#ifndef CUDAPATH_H_
#define CUDAPATH_H_

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "extrafunctions.h"

void test();


#endif /* CUDAPATH_H_ */
```

cudatest.cu:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "extrafunctions.h"

__global__ void kernel(int* devInts){
    int tid = threadIdx.x + (blockDim.x*blockIdx.x);

    if (tid == 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < NUMINTS; i++){
            devInts[i] = increment(devInts[i]);
        }
    }
}

void test(){

    int* myInts = (int*)malloc(NUMINTS * sizeof(int));
    int* devInts;
    cudaMemcpy((void**)devInts, myInts, NUMINTS*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(devInts);
    int* outInts = (int*)malloc(NUMINTS * sizeof(int));
    cudaFree(devInts);
    free(myInts);
    free(outInts);
}
```

extrafunctions.h:

```
#ifndef EXTRAFUNCTIONS_H_
#define EXTRAFUNCTIONS_H_

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define NUMINTS 4

int __device__ increment(int i);

#endif /* EXTRAFUNCTIONS_H_ */
```

extrafunctions.cu:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "extrafunctions.h"


int __device__ increment(int i){
    return i+1;
}
```

Comment: If you can create a simple reproducer, it would help.  It may be a c/c++ linkage problem.  For me anyway, there's not enough info in your post to guess at what is going on.  Even if you posted your compile command lines, it might help.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I reworded it to include a short example that replicates the problem and the compile command lines & output.

Comment: Somehow we need to get nsight EE to issue this command instead of the 2nd compile command you have posted: `nvcc -dc -G -I/usr/local/cuda/include -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_30,code=compute_30 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30  -x cu -o  "cudatest.o" "../cudatest.cu"`  How exactly is this project set up in nsight EE?  What type of project do you have specified?  The --compile switch is telling the compiler to generate non-relocatable device code, which must have all it's link points fixed up. -dc creates relocatable (essentially unlinked) code.

Comment: @RobertCrovella There's no option to enable device-compile (-dc) through a checkbox in the project properties but I edited the Command Line Pattern to ${COMMAND} -dc ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX} ${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} which gets both the example and my original project to compile.

Comment: But I can't compile a g++ linked project that uses the library now.  I get an error "undefined reference to '__cudaRegisterLinkedBinary_43...'.  My library include order is -lm, -lcudapath, -lcuda -lcudart -lbz2 (-lcudapath is my static library)

Comment: what command line are you using to create the example  library (out of extrafunctions.o and cudatest.o)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly enable separate compilation for this to work. Right-click your project, "Properties", Build->CUDA and select "Separate compilation" linker mode.

Please note that separate compilation only works on SM 2.0+ GPUs and can only emit SASS (e.g. it is not possible to emit PTX that will be compatible with future CUDA devices). For more information please read "Using Separate Compilation in CUDA" in [NVCC manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#using-separate-compilation-in-cuda).

**Update**
You need to use NVCC linker to link device code, that is why GCC linker fails. In Nsight you can either link the whole application using NVCC or setup a static library project that contains all CUDA code and is built with NVCC tollchain and a regular C/C++ project that uses GCC and links with the static library produced from the first project.